# elasticsearch nested range query

Tags: elasticsearch

Suppose i want this structure for a document:

```
{
  "hours": {
    "open": [
      {
        "start": 10,
        "end": 19
      },
      {
        "start": 21,
        "end": 29
      }
      ...
    ],
    "closed": [
      {
        "start": 100,
        "end": 199
      },
      {
        "start": 201,
        "end": 299
      }
      ...
    ]
  }
}
```

whose index has this mapping:

```
{
  "mappings": {
    "_doc": {
      "properties": {
        "hours": {
          "properties": {
            "open": {
              "type": "nested",
              "properties": {
                "start": { "type": "integer" },
                "end": { "type": "integer" }
              }
            },
            "closed": {
              "type": "nested",
              "properties": {
                "start": { "type": "integer" },
                "end": { "type": "integer" }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

In the Elasticsearch Query DSL, how do i find all documents where **20** lies inside an open segment and not inside a closed segment. The query I tried was incorrect.

### failed query

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "bool": {
            "must": [
              {
                "nested": {
                  "path": "hours.open",
                  "query": {
                    "range": {
                      "hours.open.start": { "lte": 20 }
                    }
                  }
                }
              },
              {
                "nested": {
                  "path": "hours.open",
                  "query": {
                    "range": {
                      "hours.open.end": { "gte": 20 }
                    }
                  }
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        },
        {
          "bool": {
            "must_not": [
              {
                "bool": {
                  "must": [
                    {
                      "nested": {
                        "path": "hours.closed",
                        "query": {
                          "range": {
                            "hours.closed.start": { "lte": 20 }
                          }
                        }
                      }
                    },
                    {
                      "nested": {
                        "path": "hours.closed",
                        "query": {
                          "range": {
                            "hours.closed.end": { "gte": 20 }
                          }
                        }
                      }
                    }
                  ]
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

whats wrong with my query? it is returning this document which is not what i intended. 20 does not lie inside an open segment.

Comment: Please show the query you tried

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I finally got it working.  The following is the correct query:

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "nested": {
            "path": "hours.open",
            "query": {
              "bool": {
                "must": [
                  { "range": { "hours.open.start": { "lte": 20 } } },
                  { "range": { "hours.open.end": { "gte": 20 } } }
                ]
              }
            }
          }
        }
      ],
      "must_not": [
        {
          "nested": {
            "path": "hours.closed",
            "query": {
              "bool": {
                "must": [
                  { "range": { "hours.closed.start": { "lte": 20 } } },
                  { "range": { "hours.closed.end": { "gte": 20 } } }
                ]
              }
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

With that said, it looks like my original attempt was wrong because there were two different `hours.open` nested path queries and likewise two different `hours.closed` nested path queries. The parser must only take one of them for a single path.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you need to swap lte and gte:

```
"hours.open.start": { "gte": 20 }
"hours.open.end": { "lte": 20 }
```

and same for the closing times:

```
"hours.closed.start": { "gte": 20 }
"hours.closed.end": { "lte": 20 }
```

**Edit**:
The must and must_not need to be part of the same bool query:

```
{
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "must": [{
                    "nested": {
                        "path": "hours.open",
                        "query": {
                            "range": {
                                "hours.open.start": {
                                    "gte": 20
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                },
                {
                    "nested": {
                        "path": "hours.open",
                        "query": {
                            "range": {
                                "hours.open.end": {
                                    "lte": 20
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            ],
            "must_not": [{
                "bool": {
                    "must": [{
                            "nested": {
                                "path": "hours.closed",
                                "query": {
                                    "range": {
                                        "hours.closed.start": {
                                            "gte": 20
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            "nested": {
                                "path": "hours.closed",
                                "query": {
                                    "range": {
                                        "hours.closed.end": {
                                            "lte": 20
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                }
            }]
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: your missing some braces/brackets

Comment: @Vincent sorted

Comment: this is still returning the document.