# Elastic Search searching within arrays with should clause

Tags: elasticsearch

I have an item in my index which contains a field which is an array. This array contains items with date fields "from" and "to". "From" is always set but "to" can be empty. With my query I don't seem to be able to find this specific item.

```
{
    id: 1234,
    items: [
        {
            from: 1993-01-01,
            to: 2007-11-12
        },
        {
            from: 2007-11-13,
        },
    ]
}
```

This is my query :

```
{
   "bool": {
     "must": [
       {
         "bool": {
           "should": [
             {
               "range": {
                 "to": {
                   "gte": 2019
                 }
               }
             },
             {
               "bool": {
                 "must_not": [
                   {
                     "exists": {
                       "field": "to"
                     }
                   }
                 ]
               }
             }
           ]
         }
       },
       {
         "range": {
           "from": {
             "lte": "2023-12-31T23:59:59.999"
           }
         }
       }
     ],
   }
 }
```

I was hoping, that my item from above would show up in the search results.

It would seem that the OR/SHOULD clauses are evaluated to false – each of
them for another element in the array.
E.g. :

```
{
    "range": {
        "to": {
            "gte": 2019
        }
    }
}
```

evaluates to false for the first item and not applicable for the second.

```
{
    "bool": {
        "must_not": [
            {
                "exists": {
                    "field": "to"
                }
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

evaluates to false for the first item.

So false OR false => false – no item is found.

If this thesis is correct, how to tell ES that if one of the items in the array matches one of the conditions, the item should be in the result set.

Comment: Field items is nested type?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use the [nested field type](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/nested.html) and nested query for the items field.

> The nested type is a specialised version of the object data type that
> allows arrays of objects to be indexed in a way that they can be
> queried independently of each other.

Here is a similar [stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50524770/elasticsearch-nested-range-query).

Answer (score 0):

Without using a nested field – [as Musab Dogan suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76019781/10871073) – which will boost the number of documents in your index and therefore may have performance impacts, I see another possibility to fix, but you have to change the mapping of the index and the indexing of your documents.

This is introducing a `null_value` for `items.to`. But you will have to explicitly define those (currently just missing) properties of your documents with `null`.

**To explain, why your query is not working:** Arrays respectively the values in an array are flattened by default
(See: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/array.html) and not existing fields / values are skipped:

> An array may contain null values, which are either replaced by the configured null_value or skipped entirely. An empty array [] is treated as a missing field — a field with no values.

Thus, the document you are querying looks like:

```
{
    id: 1234,
    items.from: [ 1993-01-01, 2007-11-13 ],
    items.to: [ 2007-11-12 ]
}
```

See https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/8.7/nested.html#nested-arrays-flattening-objects

But if you define the field `items.to` with an applicable and reasonable `null_value` in your use case (assuming, no `items.to` means something like "not yet known but in the future" this probably could be "2999-12-31"), change the mapping accordingly *and* index the `items.to` with explicit `null` if not given, your query would work as expected.

So, if you change the mapping to:

```
{
   ....
    "mappings": {
        "_doc": {
            "properties": {
                ....
                "items": {
                    "properties": {
                        ....
                        "to": {
                          "type": "date",
                          "null_value": "2999-12-31"
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and index documents with an explicit `null` as `items.to`:

```
{
   "id": 1234,
   "items": [
     {
       "from": "1993-01-01",
       "to": "2007-11-12"
     },
     {
       "from": "2007-11-13",
       "to": null
     }
   ]
}
```

your query would work as expected, because the flattened document you are querying looked like this:

```
{
    id: 1234,
    items.from: [ 1993-01-01, 2007-11-13 ],
    items.to: [ 2007-11-12, 2999-12-31 ]
}
```

---

**Edit:** There is a BUT ...
Assuming, you are looking for one item in the `items` array, which fulfill the conditions (this is one item has a `from` and `to` within a certain time range), this way is not accurate, because the hits refers to any of the dates in each of the flattened arrays.
Thus, you will also find a document which has a first item with `from` and `to` both before the range you are searching for and another item with `from` and `to` both after the range you are searching for.
To prevent this, using a nested array – as @musab-dogan said – is the only way to achieve the desired.